# Difference between underscore's each and ES5 forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, underscore.js, ecmascript-5

I have

```
_.each(this.fields, function(field, idx) {
```

and I thought I could change it to

```
this.fields.forEach(function(field, idx) {
```

without breaking anything.

Is there actually a difference between underscore's `each` and the native JS implementation `forEach`?

Comment: What happened when you changed it?

Comment: The underlying implementation is different, yes.

Comment: It says `TypeError: this.fields.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Well if one of them works and the other throws an error then yes, there is a difference.

Comment: @Jamgreen: `_.each` works on "collections", that is arrays and objects, while `.forEach` is an `Array` method. What is `this.fields`?

Comment: `this.fields` is an object `Object {name: Object, age: Object}`.

Answer (score 3):

Using a library i.e., underscore or lodash, you can write your code comfortably without having to worry about compatibility issues in different browsers.

Also the second advantage you get is `_.each` can iterate over an `object` too:

```
_.each([1, 2, 3], alert);
=> alerts each number in turn...

_.each({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, alert);
=> alerts each number value in turn...
```

example from http://underscorejs.org/#each

Comment: To iterate over objects, use `Object.keys(this.fields).forEach(function(key) { var field = this.fields[key]; ... });`

Comment: What compatibility issues between browsers are there with `forEach`?

Comment: I mentioned in general that compatibility issues are handled by libraries like jQuery, Underscore etc. Not specifically for `forEach` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another point not often specified, is that _.each deals with `null` and `undefined` cases, where `forEach` will throw an error.

But, for this kind of operations, I highly recommend to use the native `forEach`. This way, your skills will not be dependent to a library. It is more valuable to be a JS expert than an underscore expert (of course, exceptions exist).

One more point, here is a syntax to deal with `null` and `undefined` with a native `forEach` :

```
array?.forEach?.(element => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Do it if you have to. Cause this kind of syntax says a lot in a code, with or without interrogation mark, it means "I'm 100% sure I have an array here" or "I'm not sure if it is an array or not". If you are 99.99% sure, use interrogation mark.